# How do I fix DNS queries overload problem?

Tags: web, dns, cloudflare, ddos, websecurity

I’m facing a big problem in DNS queries recently it happens two times daily i guess with over 700 dns queries and it used to be even more like 1300 in just single second , it seems as some sort of sophisticated DNS DDOS attack or something , any tips or ways to help and avoid such ones.

problem shown in photo below.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G3qeM.jpg)

I tried adding few WAF rules but it didn't help that much.